# How to show and hide the "Please wait" message for user

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a code that executes for some time on GUI thread (to simplify things, let's assume in Button_Click event).

When the method starts I'd like to show a message "Please wait", and continue working. When the work is done I'll hide the message and continue.

I know I can do this with `BackgroundWorker` (or any other Thread related), but I was hoping there's something already finished like:

```
MBox.Show("Please wait...");
//do my work...
MBox.Hide();
```

Comment: You don't want to do work on the main UI thread... It will lock up your interface and make your app look like it's crashed. Always do it on a background thread if its anything but trivial. What's more is that with a MessageBox there is no way for a user to know how long your task is going to run for, really you want a progress bar if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using .Net 4 you can run a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to work with your  background worker, else you can do threading, but they shouldn't be in same thread.

Answer (score 3):

If you have some long running process, you should not be doing this in the UI thread.  What is wrong with `BackgoundWorker`?  That class is great!  I would recommend that you use that if this is a WinForms app.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own form to do this. There is nothing inherently evil about making the user wait if they would expect to wait or are required to wait. We have applications where the normal work flow requires a short wait. Placing it in a background thread doesn't help the user since they still need to wait for the operation to finish before they can do anything else.